# Regarding Hadoop distribution to use?

Tags: hadoop

We are planning to learn and use Hadoop for small prototyping. Not in production for now.
Which distribution of Hadoop is good to start with?
We have already installed Hadoop 0.20.2 and practicing. But Apache distribution is not compatible with Sqoop and some other things. To learn security we have to go for Hadoop 1.0.0 which is currently in beta version.

Could you, please, tell us which distribution and version of Hadoop is good to learn and prototyping.

Comment: Why do you care about beta status of hadoop 1.0.0 if you're using it for learning purposes, not for the production?

Answer (score 0):

Download the code from trunk (or 0.23 branch) and do a build, it should have all the features. Or else download the [0.23 release](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/releases.html#11+Nov,+2011%3a+release+0.23.0+available), it should have all the features till date except MRv1.